# Applying multiple functions to pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to sort by the maximum value of a column such as:

```
    dfWinners = df_new_out['Margin'].apply[max().sort_values(ascending=False)]
```

But am unsure of how to use the apply function for multiple methods such as max and sort. 
I'm sure it's a very simple problem but I cannot for the life of me find it through searching on here.
Thank you!

Comment: Sorting will give you the max value anyways, so calling `sort_values(ascending=False)` should be enough.

Comment: `apply` with `lambda`

Comment: You haven't sufficiently described your problem.  Sort what?  Do you want to place columns in the order of which column has the largest max for that column?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified more. I need to apply the maximum function, and then sort that new maximum functioned column in descending order (If that makes sense) I can clarify more if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do by assigning to `dfWinners`

If you intend dfWinners to be a list of sorted maximum to minimum values as you've described above then you can use the native `sorted()` method of python.

```
dfWinners = sorted(df_new_out['Margin'])
```

Else, you can sort your dataframe in place

```
df_new_out.sort_values(by = ['Margin'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Not really necessary I guess, could use the second option. My problem is I'm getting errors as such: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Comment: @andrewfay Sorry, edited.  the columns are parameters